# rails 4 updating object invoke the creation of a related model same action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, polymorphism, http-status-code-302

In my crm app there is opportunity model and comment model (polymorphic that can belong to opportunity).
I have status_edit and status_update actions which has a form to change opportunity status.
i would like that action to invoke the creation of a new comment. (there is other ways to create comments that already works well). the opportunity is been updated but new associated comment isn't.

```
 def status_update
   @opportunity.update(opportunity_params)
   if @opportunity.save
     @comment = @opportunity.comments.new(name: "Status was changed to #{@opportunity.status}", description: "#{@opportunity.status_reason}")
     @comment.save!
     redirect_to opportunity_path(@opportunity)
     ...
 end
```

server log :

```
  SQL (1.5ms)  UPDATE "crm_opportunities" SET "status" = ?, "updated_at" = ? WHERE "crm_opportunities"."id" = ?  [["status", 3], ["updated_

at", "2020-02-23 07:07:33.936820"], ["id", 26]]
   (16.6ms)  commit transaction
   (0.2ms)  begin transaction
   (0.1ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/crm_opportunities/26
Completed 302 Found in 45ms (ActiveRecord: 19.4ms)
```

routes:

```
  resources :opportunities do
    resources :comments
    member do
      get :status_edit
      patch :status_update
    end
  end
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

since comments is belongs to Opportunity, you can use build to create new record for comments

below is sample for the creation of comment

```
 @comment = @opportunity.comments.build(name: "Status was changed to #{@opportunity.status}", description: "#{@opportunity.status_reason}")
 @comment.save
```

if the above method still fail please check also validation that you set in comment model

Comment: thank you, i worked it out with a callback in the opportunity model